# Virtualbox window cutoof

Tags: screen, aptana, virtualbox, graphic

[image: Screen Shot]

In the image, the More Options are clearly cuut off from windows. There is no scrolling bar for me to access those options. I tried to change the resolutions. This picture is taken in Seamless mode, and in Scale mode, "more options" is not displayed. If anyone can tell me how to set this/tweak it, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lower the screen resolution in your Virtual Machine to less than or equal to your resolution in your Physical PC.